# updating model from another controller doesn't update ui

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

i have 1 model and two controllers

```
App.Measure= DS.Model.extend({
name:DS.attr('string')
});
```

and two controller:

```
App.ModelController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

and

```
 App.MeasuresController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:['Application','Measure'],
  setMeasure:function(name){
    this.get('controllers.Measure').set('model',App.Measures.find(name));
}
 });
```

App.Measures is a ember object that have ajax request and update model of measure.but when i can see ajax request is  successful in chrome developer tools but the ui doesn't update. ui is a component that set to model

```
{{tree node=model}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is to use lower cased names for the controllers you `need`:

```
App.MeasuresController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:['application','measure'],
  setMeasure:function(name){
    this.get('controllers.measure').set('model',App.Measures.find(name));
  }
});
```

And depending on the version of ember-data you use, e.g. in version 1.0.0 this line should read:

```
this.get('controllers.measure').set('model', this.store('measures').find(name));
```

Hope it helps.